# NSArray error: "!Expression is not assignable"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have created an NSArray which I have initialized to contain the attributes of a core data entity. When I later try to set these attributes through the Array I get the error  "!Expression is not assignable". How do I set the values of the attributes by referencing them through the NSArray? Here are the relevant portions of my code:

```
    headingArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                heading1,
                heading2,
                heading3, ...
```

heading1, heading2, ... are attributes of the core data entity

```
    for (int i=1; [note.headingCount intValue]-1; i++) {
    [note.headingArray objectAtIndex:i] = selectedTemplateForNote.heading1;
  }
```

the [note.headingArray objectAtIndex:i] is the code that is flagged with the error "!Expression is not assignable".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSArray` are immutable. You can not change their content without constructing a new array. Try using an `NSMutableArray` and `- (void)replaceObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index withObject:(id)anObject;` instead.

**Editing based on new info:**

You are probably trying to do the following then:

```
NSManagedObject *entity = ...;
for (int i=1; [note.headingCount intValue]-1; i++) {
    [entity setValue:selectedTemplateForNote.heading1 forKey:[note.headingArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

Comment: I should further explain that I am trying to use the array to reference the core data entity attributes. I don't want the array to contain a copy of the attributes. What I want to do is read and write the core data entity attributes, but do so through a reference (pointer) contained in the array. This way I can use a for loop to index throughout the attributes. cc:@diatrevolo, @Jens

Comment: Updated answer trying to anticipate what you are really trying to do.

Comment: That is going in the right direction. Explaining further, "note" is of type "Notes" which is an automatically generated NSManagedObject subclass (select Xcode menu -> Editor select -> Create NSManagedObject subclass). Using your code I would use "[note setValue:selectedTemplateForNote.heading1 forKey:[note.headingArray objectAtIndex:i]];". I think that will work, but with the subclass I created I think there should be a simpler way of contracting the statement that hides the core data key/value store syntax. Any further comments on how to do that.

Comment: Not off hand. Other possibility is using `-[NSKeyValueCoding setValueForKeysWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict];` but that probably won't buy you anything in long run.

Comment: I've run into another problem: heading1, heading2, ... heading36 are properties of the NSManagedObject note. As such, I don't think it is valid to put them in the headingArray as I have done. My goal is to access these properties in a loop by index rather than having to write 36 statements each time. Any suggestions?

Comment: `NSManagedObject` is KVC compliant, so instead of assigning the actual attributes (which indeed you can not do, and did not know that's what those were in your sample, thought they held string values), assign a string representation of the property @"heading1", @"heading2", etc, and the code I suggested will work (although your for loops is missing its invariant, but that may be just a typo?)

Comment: Great that worked. Thanks for all your help. Yes, that was a typo. Should be "for (int i=0; i<=[note.headingCount intValue]-1; i++)".

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C you cannot assign values like this.  You'll need to do something like:

```
NSMutableArray* tempArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:note.headingArray];
for (int i=1; [note.headingCount intValue]-1; i++) {
    [tempArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:selectedTemplateForNote.heading1];
}
[note setHeadingArray:[NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray]];
```

Answer (score -1):

What type is selectedTemplateForNote.heading1? Make sure, it is a NSValue!

Comment: selectedTemplateForNote.heading1 is a core data entity attribute of type string.